# Why does the output give 00246 instead of 0013610

Tags: c, recursion

I was in C today and I saw this example of using recursive calls and I don't understand how it works. Can someone please explain?

```
int print(int nb)
{
    if (nb < 0) 
    {
        return (0);
    }
    printf("%d", nb + print(nb - 1));
    nb --;
    return (nb);
}

int main(void)
{
    print(4);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think it should give `0013610` as the output?

Comment: The best way to understand recursion is to run your code line by line in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471), while monitoring the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and the values of all variables.

Comment: I removed [unix] and [assembly] tags, as they seem irrelevant to this. This is portable C (as long as implicit declaration of printf works without `#include <stdio.h>`), and doesn't depend on being run on Unix.  And unless I'm missing some C undefined behaviour, its behaviour can be explained without looking at how it compiles to assembly.  **Single-step it in a debugger,** with a watch / display set on `nb`.

Comment: Start simple. What would it print for `print(0)` ? For `print(1)`? And so on.

Comment: I suggest that you split the line `printf("%d", nb + print(nb - 1));` into two lines: `int temp =  print(nb - 1); <insert newline here> printf("%d", nb + temp );` That way, the behavior of your program will be much clearer when running it line by line in a debugger, as you won't have multiple things happening in a single line.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The confusing part is the line with the `nb --;`

Comment: What is confusing about it? You don't know what the `--` operator does?

Comment: `nb --;` is equivalent to `nb = nb - 1;`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know it is supposed to reduce the value of the variable. But the code has this `nb - 1` already. Does that mean the reduction happens before of after that line or it happens after the recursion.

Comment: Both the recursive call parameter and the return value are the original `nb` minus one. You can easily track it down. You could put `nb--` before the `printf` line, and then remove the `-1` from the recursive call (and add `+1` to the printed result)  and get the same result.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The first value is 4.
The function would evaluate it as 4 +print (4-1) which is 4 + print (3).
Then print (3) would be 3 + print(2) and so on till the result is less than 0.

Comment: @Afebu print(3) does not return 3+print(2). It prints 3+print(2), then it returns something else.

Comment: Okay @EugeneSh. I would try that out. Thanks.

Comment: The expression `nb - 1` does not change the value of the variable `nb`. The expressions `nb = nb - 1` and `nb--` (which are equivalent) however do change the value of the variable `nb`.

Answer (score 2):

> *The confusing part is the line with the `nb --;`*

This is the post-decrement operator. You can read about it here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec

It decrements `nb` (subtracts one from it), then returns the original value of `nb`. So, if `nb` is originally 3, it sets `nb` to 2 and returns 3.

Your code ignores the returned value, so it's effectively equivalent to `nb = nb - 1;`.